# Replace multiple occurrence of words in string PHP

Tags: php

I just want to replace the following string:

```
This is my first sentence.
.:.
This is my second sentence.
.:.
This is my third sentence.
.:.
```

The output should be like:

```
This is my first sentence.
1
This is my second sentence.
2
This is my third sentence.
3
```

How can I do it in more efficient and easy way?

Comment: Take a look here [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Can you get the idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/@/",
    function(){static $count=0; return ++$count;},
    "A@B@C@");
```

Comment: All sentences are stored in $string. Should i replace "A@B@C@" with $string?

Comment: Yep, and the `"/@/"` with the actual pattern you are replacing.

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working. preg_replace_callback(".:.",
    function(){static $count=0; return ++$count;},
    $Product_description);

Comment: That would be a pattern with `.` as delimiters.... and matching all literal `:`'s.... I doubt that is what you want. If you are having trouble creating the proper regex, I suggest posing it as a new question.